GRPC API's giving 500 status code with auto-instrumentation
File "/microservice/python/seldon_core/microservice.py", line 477, in            _run_grpc_serverserver = seldon_microservice.get_grpc_server(File "/microservice/python/seldon_core/wrapper.py", line 301, in get_grpc_serverserver = grpc.server(File "/otel-auto-instrumentation-python/opentelemetry/instrumentation/grpc/init.py", line 338, in serverkwargs["interceptors"].insert(AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert')

I am getting the above error when I add auto-instrumentation (OTEL) in the pod. Also, calling the grpc API's gives 500 Internal server error with the below detail:
{
     "requestId": "x",
     "errorType": "FunctionExecutionException",
     "httpStatus": 500,
     "links": [
            {
                "rel": "log",
                "href": "api/log?podName=abc&traceId=xyz"
            }
      ],
     "message": "Function id: wO407eQc with input: z"
}

We are using the seldon-core base image to use it's grpc functionality out of the box. So, I didn't try anything.
